# Interval for which $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, maxima-minima

> The largest interval for which $x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0$ is :

$$
x^{12}-x^9+x^4-x+1>0\\
x(x^3-1)(x^8+1)+1>0\\
x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^8+1)+1>0
$$
I can see that this is satisfied for $x\in(-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty)$. But how can I verify the above function is greater than zero when $x\in(0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{12}+x^4(1-x^5)+(1-x)>0$$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: okay. Is there a better way to see this, by using may be differentiation ?. instead of converting it into two different forms to verify different domains.

Comment: Try to calculate the derivative and stationary points for minimum.

Comment: won't that be even more cumbersome involving higher order terms ?